# How do I combine these two select queries?

Tags: mysql

Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            username,
            nickname,
            email
        FROM
            accounts
        WHERE
            id = 1
    ) AS accdetails,
    (
        SELECT
            rank
        FROM
            ranks
        WHERE
            userid = 1
        AND group = "admin"
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS rank;
```

This works, but only if the user has a rank on the group called "admin". I'd like it to return null for the rank if it doesn't exist, but still return the user's username, nickname and email.

I've also tried using a left join, but I can't seem to get that working right either. The same issue occurs. Both tables can be joined using `ON accounts.id=ranks.userid`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
SELECT a.username, a.nickname, a.email, a.id, r.rank
FROM accounts a 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ranks r on a.id = r.userid and r.group = 'admin';
```

Comment: That query returns all account usernames, nicknames, emails and IDs. I want to get the username, nickname and email for ID 1 only. Edit: I got it working by adding `WHERE a.id=1;` at the end. Thanks! I'll mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use a  left join

```
SELECT    *
FROM  (
        SELECT
            username,
            nickname,
            email, 
            id
        FROM             accounts
        WHERE             id = 1
    )  accdetails
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT             rank
        FROM             ranks
        WHERE             userid = 1
        AND group = "admin"
        LIMIT 1
    )  ranks on accdetails.id = ranks.userid;
```

Comment: `rank on accdetailsi.id = rank.userid;` Is this part right? I feel like you made a typo and it should be `rank ON accdetails.id = ranks.userid;`. But I've tried that and it says that ranks.userid is an unknown column even though it exists

Comment: @JDel   .  thanks  is typo i  have update  the answer .. hope these are the right  tables and columns name ...` accdetails.id = ranks.userid`